# Tensorflow: Linear model diverges when adding examples to the training vector

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, linear-regression

First, apologies if I'm making a silly mistake - this is one of my first tensorflow programs. To my defense - I've searched the subject and did not find any reasonable explanation.

## The code

The code is adapted from the [Getting Started guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started). It uses a gradient  to train a simple linear model:

```python
import tensorflow as tf

# Define a linear model. The initial values are wrong (W=0.3, b=0.3),
# and should converge to (W=-1, b=1).

# Variables
W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# Linear model
linear_model = W * x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# Loss function and optimizer
square_deltas = tf.square(linear_model - y)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(square_deltas)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# Tensorflow session
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# Train!
for i in range(100):
    sess.run(train, {x:[1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
                     y:[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5]})
print(sess.run([W, b]))
```

## Results

When the model is trained for 100 times, the result is:

```
[array([-0.97550046], dtype=float32), array([ 0.89605999], dtype=float32)]
```

When the model is trained 1000 times, the result is closer to (-1, 1), as expected:

```
[array([-0.9999997], dtype=float32), array([ 0.99999875], dtype=float32)]
```

## The problem

When adding another example to the training sample:

```
sess.run(train, {x:[1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
                 y:[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]})
```

The results diverge (100 and 1000 iterations, respectively):

```
[array([  1.65981654e+28], dtype=float32), array([  3.35185014e+27], dtype=float32)]
[array([ nan], dtype=float32), array([ nan], dtype=float32)]
```

**Why does adding another example fail the model?**

Comment: change learning rate to 0.001, also reduce_sum should be reduce_mean (otherwise learning rate changes meaning when you add more samples)

Answer (score 0):

By adding new single data, due to short size of previous data, you are increasing number of data about 15% ! This is a big change especially when your new data is very different from samples in current train data. You can not solve the problem by only increasing learning iteration, since gradient step can not compensate fluctuation in train data. Just decrease gradient step which will result in slower adopting to training data.